# Two Java Runtime Environments on one OS, but with different architectures?

Tags: x86, 64-bit, java

Will two JREs on one system conflict with each other if they have different architecture? I use Windows 7 x64 and currently I have installed x64 JRE 6 update 27, but when for example I try to start `minecraft` in `Chrome` or any other browser I get a pop, that browser might need x32 for that.

Any thoughts on that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to have both x86 and x64 JREs on an x64 system.  Some applications require the x86, and some others will take advantage of x64 if it's there.

Comment: So, the main thing is, that I can install both. They will work together just fine.

Comment: Correct.  You can also safely have 1.5 versions, 1.6, and 1.7 all at the same time.  :-)